# Where is the symmetry of Fourier transform in its implementation in Maxima and Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-analysis

From Wikipedia I saw that there is a symmetry of the Fourier transformation

$F(F(f))(x) = f(-x)$

This matches the graphical explanation of the (German) [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QjMFOtgx_A) (9:15 to 9:45).

I tried to see that symmetry in various tools, but somehow it does not match my expected result.

My input: `[1, 0, 0, 0]`

Expected output: `[0, 0, 0, 1]`

[The example `fft(fft([1,0,0,0])` in Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fft%28fft%28[1%2C0%2C0%2C0]%29%29) produces `[1, 0, 0, 0]` as output.

The wxMaxima script

```
load(fft);
Input:[1,0,0,0];
Once: fft(Input);
Twice: fft(Once);
```

results in `[0.25, 0, 0, 0]`.

So now I am confused twice:

- why do Wolfram and Maxima produce different output?
- where is the symmetry? Is it because of the optimization of FFT, so I should use DFT to get better results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your expected output is wrong. For the purpose of the Fourier transform, the array is `0`-indexed. In terms of Fourier transform on finite groups, the first element is the value for the function evaluated on the identity element. In any case, $-0 = 0$. So you should expect that the double Fourier transform of 
   $$ [a,b,c,d] $$
   to be
   $$ [a, d, c, b] $$

   Therefore [Wolfram does it as expected](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fft%28fft%28[1%2C2%2C3%2C4]%29%29).
2. There are two main ways of [normalizing the Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Other_conventions) (on finite groups). The first method (as assumed by Wikipedia and Wolfram), takes
   $$ \hat{f}(s) = \langle f(x), \chi_s(x) \rangle $$
   where $\chi_s$ is the corresponding irreducible character (basically $e^{isx}$). Then the inverse transform is given by 
   $$ f(x) = \frac{1}{|G|} \langle \hat{f}(s), \bar{\chi}_s(x)\rangle $$
   where $|G|$ is the size of the group (the number of elements).

   The other method is to make the two formulae more symmetrical by definiting the forward transform as
   $$ \hat{f}(s) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{|G|}} \langle f(x), \chi_s(x)\rangle $$
   and now the inverse transform will also have just the square-root factor. Evidently Maxima chooses this latter normalisation which means that in its implementation 
   $$ \mathcal{F}(\mathcal{F}(f))(x) = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{|G|}}\right)^2 f(-x) $$
   which accounts for the difference of a factor of 4 (your group is of size 4).